# MFMailComposeViewController crash

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios7.1

So I run the code below to present the mail form, and it crashes on me. I run out of ideas at this point. Anyone?

Code:

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));

if (mailClass != nil && [mailClass canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Subject"];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But it crashes

```
-[UIDeviceRGBColor shadowOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc135710  


0   CoreFoundation                      0x02c2f1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028f98e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02ccc243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02c1f50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x02c1f0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIKit                               0x014763fe -[UINavigationItemView _currentTextShadowOffsetForBarStyle:] + 132
6   UIKit                               0x014766b2 -[UINavigationItemView _updateLabelContents] + 396
7   UIKit                               0x01476ef1 -[UINavigationItemView _titleSize] + 51
8   UIKit                               0x01476806 -[UINavigationItemView _labelFrame] + 80
9   UIKit                               0x01475f60 -[UINavigationItemView initWithNavigationItem:] + 416
10  UIKit                               0x0144ad5a -[UINavigationItem _defaultTitleView] + 116
11  UIKit                               0x01447808 -[UINavigationItem _addDefaultTitleViewToNavigationBarIfNecessary] + 50
12  UIKit                               0x01447eb2 -[UINavigationItem setTitle:] + 212
13  MessageUI                           0x0073ac96 -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController viewDidLoad] + 593
14  UIKit                               0x014cb33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
```

Notes: my class is a `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and I do implement the required method.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. It was caused by using the appearance proxy, but then not having a top navigation bar.

So I set the 
[UINavigationBar appearance]
but then I have changed my mind during the project and went with UI without the default navigation.